# How to create browser alert in node,js

Tags: node.js

I want that when the user submits the form a popup appears in the browser that shows that form submitted successfully. I know how to create it in javascript but how to do it in node.js.

```
app.post('/post',(request,response)=>{
    var description=request.body.description;
    var contact_number=request.body.contact_number;
    var city=request.body.city;
    var budget=request.body.budget;
    var category=request.body.optradio;                    
   var query=connection.query("insert into jobs(Jobs_id,Description,Category,City,Contact_number,Budget) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)",[null,description,category,city,contact_number,budget],function(err){
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else
        response.send("successful");

        }); 
    });
```

I want to handle it in the else part. I want to show alert message instead of sending **successful** to the browser. I will appreciate if anyone could help me :)

Comment: Look up toast messages. In node.js here is a library for such: https://www.npmjs.com/package/toastr You will also need this library which parses the response. https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: You should send an error response to the browser & add a logic which checks & alerts in the front-end

Comment: are you using ajax for post data from frontend to backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**using flash**

```
var flash = require('connect-flash');
app.use(flash());

 if(err)
        console.log(err);
    else
      req.flash('success', 'successfull');
      res.locals.message = req.flash();
    }
```

pug template

```
if message
  for msg in message
    div.alert.alert-success #{ msg }
```

this will work charm.

Comment: i am supposed to place this ajax code in the node.js file??

Comment: ajax code will be written on your frontend page, (.html, .ejs any)